# How come the video sequence editor does not show an accurate representation of render output, but "show backdrop" does?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

This is an issue I ran into while editing last night. I repeated a video clip, added a transform layer on top and cropped it, moving it into position as seen in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDp9h.png). When rendering, it did not show up. Out of curiosity, I clicked "show backdrop" and noticed the overlay absent. I had noticed the same problem using the text tool, where it would appear to fit in the video sequence editor, but would show cut off in the render. 
I did, however, discover that the "show backdrop" feature actually accurately displayed what the render would show. So my question is, why on earth is that video output string not shown in the VSE window, and what can I do to fix it?
[image: An image directly showing the discrepancy of the video sequence editor and the "use backdrop"]